# SSRS Matrix Title Being Cut Off

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Could someone please explain how I can have the report header (title) expand as far wide as the matrix in the report goes? The title is a textbox and only goes as far wide as I set in the report designer.

[image: photo]

I am using SSRS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a row above the top row of your matrix/tablix and then merge all the cells in that row and make that your report header.

Comment: SSRS does not allow merging cells like that. I insert a row above, and I cannot merge the cell from grouped columns, and the cell from matrix value columns.

Comment: Okay, I have done it before, but it was a tablix. I guess it doesn't work on a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution or better said my workaround, was to set the report background to the colour I wanted and just push the title alignment to the left. Now the background colour fills the width of the report.